# Heroku download postgres DB - capture works, curl is unknown

Tags: python, postgresql, curl, heroku, database-backups

I am doing this task the first time. I have found good documentation on how to download an existing postgres DB to local but none of the informations seem to work for me.

I need to download an existing postgres DB to local. I do this to check the entries and to have a backup because I need to work on the DB.

I have posgresql installed localy and I want to copy the heroku DB into my local DB which is named `postgres`. The local server has a username `postgres` and a password.

I have only one DB and one APP on heroku.

I tried 2 solutions.

**PG:PULL**

```
heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL postgres
```

This gave me:

```
 DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
 !    The command "createdb" is written either false or 
 !    could not be found
 !
 !    Unable to create new local database. Ensure your local Postgres is working and try again.
```

So I tried with password ans username:

```
PGUSER=postgres PGPASSWORD=mypw heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL postgres
```

This gave me:

```
The command "PGUSER" is written either false or could not be found
```

**PG:BACKUPS**

```
heroku pg:backups capture
```

This worked well:

```
Use Ctrl-C at any time to stop monitoring progress; the backup
will continue running. Use heroku pg:backups info to check progress.
Stop a running backup with heroku pg:backups cancel.

DATABASE ---backup---> b003

Backup completed
```

Then I used curl:

```
curl -o latest.dump `heroku pg:packups public-url`
```

Which gave me:

```
The command "curl" is written either false or could not be found
```

It seems nobody had such a problem, I dont know what I am missing. I red the whole heroku documentation and there is no such case.

**EDIT**

I connected to my DB via PgAdmin4 but also here I am getting the same type of error when trying to restore a DB dump file.

The PgAdmin4 log gives me:

```
The command "pg_restore.exe" is written either false or could not be found
```

I also tried to add postgresql to global path variable, but it does not seem to help:

```
;C:\Programme\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\pg_restore.exe
```

and I tried:

```
;C:\Programme\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin
```

Comment: Are you running on windows or linux?

Comment: Yes, I am running windows

Comment: Then you can't provide PGUSER and PGPASSWORD inline, I ended up setting them as my env variables (SET PGUSER), but that's about all I remember. I also did switch to linux eventually if that's a valid tip. When it comes to curl, you have to install that somehow - loads of people assume it's part of windows commandline by default but it's not.